# Using Java and pdfBox to search a pdf for usd amounts

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

This is for something that could save me about 10 minutes at work, I am not getting paid for it.  This is Java. Its been a while since I touched Java. I'm searching a PDF for just numbers that use USD currency form via pdfBox. This is a what the document looks a lot like.

```
Activity Report
Business Date: 10/9/2019   Property Code: me.ra777   Shift: 9   User: me.ra777
Reserve 

Account Person Name Start End Days Status Money TypeOfCode Type Location Source GTD Date User
077071543 Smith's, John Middle 9/25/19 9/26/19 1 O 55.50 BAR SNQQ 211 WI MC 9/25/19 me.ra777
877075375 45Lisa, Jo.nes Mid  9/25/19 9/26/19 1 I 99.00 SEG SNKE 138 WI VI 9/25/19 me.ra777
677256813 Jo^hn Wi.ck Ed 9/26/19 9/27/19 1 O 129.00 TRQ SNQQ 132 WI VI 9/26/19 me.ra777
477007406 Guys, Are 9/26/19 9/27/19 1 O 129.00 BAR SNQQ 133 WI VI 9/26/19 me.ra777
977495887 Last, First 9/27/19 9/28/19 1 O 165.00 BAR SNKE 438 WI VI 9/27/19 me.ra777
677472246 Po.or, Rich 9/27/19 9/28/19 1 O 165.00 BAR SNKE 138 WI MC 9/27/19 me.ra777
677457228 Dude, Isn't Here 9/27/19 9/28/19 1 I 180.00 BAR SNQQ 433 WI MC 9/27/19 me.ra777

Date/Time of Printing: 10/10/2019 1:42 PM   Software Version: ssrs7x67    Page 1 of 1
```

If I used a a method like this......

```
public static void oneLine(Scanner sc){

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {   
        String line = sc.nextLine();   
    if(line.contains(" WI ")){    
        displayArea.append("\n"+line + "\n");
        break; 
    }else{}

     }
        sc.close();
    }
```

I would only get this for my output.

> 077071543 Smith's, John Middle 9/25/19 9/26/19 1 O 55.50 BAR SNQQ 211 WI MC 9/25/19 me.ra777

My desired out put would be just

> 55.50

Maybe even all the USD amounts like this

> 55.50
>    99.00
>    129.00
>    129.00
>    165.00
>    165.00
>    180.00

Okay a little bit more data about this document. I only need the data in these lines

```
077071543 Smith's, John Middle 9/25/19 9/26/19 1 O 55.50 BAR SNQQ 211 WI MC 9/25/19 me.ra777
877075375 45Lisa, Jo.nes Mid  9/25/19 9/26/19 1 I 99.00 SEG SNKE 138 WI VI 9/25/19 me.ra777
677256813 Jo^hn Wi.ck Ed 9/26/19 9/27/19 1 O 129.00 TRQ SNQQ 132 WI VI 9/26/19 me.ra777
477007406 Guys, Are 9/26/19 9/27/19 1 O 129.00 BAR SNQQ 133 WI VI 9/26/19 me.ra777
977495887 Last, First 9/27/19 9/28/19 1 O 165.00 BAR SNKE 438 WI VI 9/27/19 me.ra777
677472246 Po.or, Rich 9/27/19 9/28/19 1 O 165.00 BAR SNKE 138 WI MC 9/27/19 me.ra777
677457228 Dude, Isn't Here 9/27/19 9/28/19 1 I 180.00 BAR SNQQ 433 WI MC 9/27/19 me.ra777
```

Everything in the those lines can change EXCEPT under source where it says "WI" AND Under User where it says "me.ra777" People can mess up names like where you see "45Lisa, Jo.nes" and "Jo^hn Wi.ck"

Ultimately I still have more work to do after this. Where I need to add all the USD amounts and actually, still a little more where I divide them by 100; which, in this example I believe would give me 9.225 if I did my math right.....

I'm really hoping I can just change part of this code like here ....

```
    if(line.contains(" WI ")){
```

So then I could at least get an output of only the lines I need and I could work a little on my own from there and try to figure the rest out on my own.

Comment: Well, you obviously get the entire line instead of the USD value only. That means you have to search for it in the line, which you can do in several different ways. One of my choices would be to `split()` the line by an arbitrary amount of whitespaces and go through the resulting `String[]` looking for an entry of the form *numeric.numeric* (a decimal number).

Comment: This very well may be all I need to figure out what I need or at least to progress. I'll keep the topic updated. After I try some things, I'll share my results. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. In short I had two major methods ----> find() & getUSD(Final String)

```
find() Used 
1. A for Loop 
2. A while(String.astNextLine)
3. If line contains("WI" && ! linecontains "Software Version " ) 
4. varable rate = getUSD(String) 
5. doSumMathStuffs'andComplainAboutWhyJavacan'tTellThisIsa#WithoutParseing 
    ;; 
6. print ("\n"+rate);

    getUSD(Final String) used 
1. If/else "Matcher m = Pattern.compile("-?\d+(\.\d+)").matcher(strings);" 
2. while(m.find) 
3 return m.group 
4. There's Actualy some parseing and some other "transfer this variable tYpE to that TyPe " too
```